# Dynamic load balancing with reverse SSH tunnels on different ports using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, elastic-load-balancer

I am working on a project where more than 50 thousand devices need to communicate with my server using reverse SSH tunneling.

These devices will also be generating, and moving heavy traffic across these ports, hence consuming heavy network and CPU on server.

I am using AWS EC2 stack, and have chosen a moderate server to start with (4 CPU cores and 16 GB RAM).

Since a single server is not capable of 50 thousand + connections, I must find a way to load balance the traffic somehow.

Assuming each EC2 instance can support up to 500 reverse SSH connections, without choking, I would require 50000/500 = 100 servers (for 50k devices: let’s assume this is the hard target for now).

While I am eventually going to require 100 servers, this increase of devices will be gradual, so I don't require 100 servers from day one.

This count should increase gradually, as the number of devices increase, which communicate with the server.

The obvious way to handle this is by Elastic Load Balancing, or maybe Elastic IP (both concepts are bit different but ELB is obviously the way to go).

But ELB would work on normal communication protocols, such as HTTP/HTTPS/TCP.

My scenario is bit different: each device is assigned a different port.

For example:

```
Dev 1 port      = 2000
Dev 2 port      = 2001
Dev 3 port      = 2003
Dev 50000 port  = 52000
```

I want whole load balancing to happen on the reverse SSH tunnels' ports, which is tad different from the whole ELB concept, to start with.

I am fine with a DNS name such as: ports.my-domain.com.

Then this DNS should be the hub of ELB, and start/stop new EC2 servers whenever required, and do port forwarding like:

```
ports.my-domain.com
|
|- 1.1.1.1 (port range: 2000-2500)
|- 1.1.1.2 (port range: 2501-3000)
|- 1.1.1.3 (port range: 3001-3500)
...
```

Obviously, the servers 1.1.1.1 - 1.1.1.3 etc. are all started and managed by ELB.

When dev 1 is establishing reverse SSH on port 2000, it is always going to be assigned same IP: 1.1.1.1, so the sticky port concept is there, which is although supported by CLB (AWS classic load balancer), but does not work for TCP ports...

I would prefer: all devices will communicate with ports.my-domain.com, and request tunneling like:

```
Dev 1       -> ports.my-domain.com: 2000
Dev 2       -> ports.my-domain.com: 2001
Dev 50000   -> ports.my-domain.com: 52000
```

Internally, this ELB will start server 1: 1.1.1.1 for first 500 connections, then 1.1.1.2 for next 500 connections, till the end, where the 50000th device will be registered on (maybe) 1.1.255.200

I only want to use forward domain name: ports.my-domain.com, and expect AWS to handle the rest.

Online AWS tutorials gives different concepts to implement, like: AWS Cloud Watch, AWS Elastic Bean stalk, AWS Cloud Formation, AWS Container services (again: docker ports concept is there which is different from my requirement) etc. but all these explanations are not exactly in this direction.

Would like to hear suggestion on what technology stack gives best implementation for my requirement.

Appreciate all feedback...

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you want to use reverse SSH?  It seems that you're creating a very complex system that already exists if you just use HTTP/S.  I've seen ElasticBeanstalk scale to hundreds of machines (and scale back down when not needed) and it's all pretty much taken care of for you.  I very well might be missing something though.  If you're assuming a continuous connection you've already got an issue.

Comment: Basically it is kind of implementation for a relay server. The devices will be sending video/audio stream to the relay server, from where it may be propagated elsewhere. 99.99% connectivity is pretty much desired; so yes, it is the condition where I require continuous connection... I just cannot imagine how HTTP/S will help me there, or maybe I completely missed something.

Comment: That makes more sense now.  You may want to look at the RTP protocol (or others like RTMP) as they have been designed for at least some of the issues you'll likely run into.  Using the classic load balancer you could scale on traffic.  Sounds like a cool product - sorry I don't have a better answer!

Comment: Many thanks for the motivation: yes! I am already using RTP protocol with back end server on devices being RTSP. I have also tried to use CLB as you mentioned, but noticed it has few short-comings so it does not fit-in 100%. I also plan to re-visit CLB, maybe I've missed something right under my nose.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? Im running in a very similar scenario.

Comment: Hi, yes: but I actually implemented the whole thing on my own.

Comment: Hey, i know it's been a while, but would you mind sharing how you were able to implement it? I am struggling to balance the ssh connections using different ports on an nlb.. For some reason, communication works perfectly only when the nlb listener is port 22 otherwise it fails.. I would appreciate any help